# replace cyrillic letters to latin

Tags: vba, replace, find, ms-word

I want make macros in VBA translating cyrillic letters to latin's.
Currently, I use

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Ш"    'cyrillic letter
    .Replacement.Text = "Sh"  'latin letter

    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

and repeat it for all letters.
This method works. But it very slowly works with large document, because more 50 times calls Selection.Find.Execute.

**Q:** Can I solve it more fastest ?
For example, something like

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^$"  'Finds any letter
    .Replacement.Text = "\\1"  ' ---> There I don't know how retrieve 
                               '    found letter 


    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False

    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Or can I solve it with another way ( Application.ActiveDocument.Characters or Application.ActiveDocument.Words, etc.) , without lose formatting?

Comment: You'd need to test which is faster, using Find or looping a document's characters. It should be possible to do something like For Each c in ActiveDocument.Characters to "walk" each character in a document. But the problem remains how to identify the characters and their replacements. If you know the unicode number for the cyrillic characters then you can test that number and "look up" the equivalent. For example the "sh" character: If Chr(c.Text) = 1064 Then 'and here call a function that returns "sh", which you write to the document.

Comment: I know how walk ActiveDocument.Characters , but dont know replace it's content?

Comment: Building on the snippet in my earlier comment, using the object c: c.Text = "sh". On thinking about it, that could get confusing for Word when you replace a single character with multiple characters. Might make sense to write a second document in the background, rather than change the original while you work...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use:

1. Remove the selections and set them as a range, if possible.
2. Disable ScreenUpdating, it shall be way better.

   ```
   Sub Replacer()

   Dim rng1 As Range

   call onstart

   Set rng1 = Activedocument.Range

   With rng1.Find
       .Text = "Ш"    'cyrillic letter
       .Replacement.Text = "Sh"  'latin letter

       .Forward = True
       .Wrap = wdFindContinue
       .Format = False
       .MatchCase = True
       .MatchWholeWord = False
       .MatchWildcards = False
       .MatchSoundsLike = False
       .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With

   call onend

   End Sub

   Public Sub OnEnd()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.StatusBar = False

   End Sub

   Public Sub OnStart()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   End Sub
   ```